# PHP DateTime returns false when passing format as a variable

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to create a date object from a date string but I am getting false if I pass the format string as a variable.

I've tried to pass it as a string `'Y-m-d'` and it's working as expected.

**Working:**

```
// $date_str = '2019-03-05';

function isValidDateFormat($date_str){
      var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date_str));
}

/* prints:

object(DateTime)[64]
  public 'date' => string '2019-03-05 06:07:53' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'America/Toronto' (length=15)
*/
```

**Not working:**

```
// $date_str = '2019-03-05';
// $format can be different based on user's choice

function isValidDateFormat($date_str, $format='Y-m-d'){
     var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date_str)); // prints boolean false
}
```

Comment: Works correctly in my side

Comment: same with me it works well

Comment: It works fine. Check it again @Sidra

Comment: which version of php ?

Comment: Yeah I just checked it on a PHP online editor. It's working good there :-( but not in my code. I am passing $format as a parameter in my function. Let me edit the question details.

Comment: @H45H It's 5.4 version

Comment: It's work fine,I tested it on PHP 5.4. Could you please check, is the file saved as UTF-8 without BOM? Just try to save the PHP file in a different encoding. Maybe Y-m-d is assumed as different symbols in your file.

Comment: Works fine.. any error you facing?

Comment: Thank you all for your time. It's a callback function that I am using for a customized validation rule in CodeIgniter and somehow it was messing with the order of the arguments. It's working okay now..